# How can I make a click event work on more than one selector?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
        $("#menu").on('click', 'a', function (event) {

            javascript code
            ...
        });

        $("#home").on('click', 'a', function (event) {

            javascript code
            ...
        });
```

Is there some way I can combine these two as the javascript code for both is the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $("#menu, #home").on('click', 'a', function() {
    //  javascript code
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this

```
$("#menu, #home").on('click', 'a', function (event) {

            javascript code
            ...
        });
```